# using setState without this in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React (also fairly new to Javascript in general) and trying to wrap my head around what can be done with setState to re-render React elements on the page.

Is there a way to use setState in one component to change the state of a completely different element (i.e. components that maybe only share the DOM root node)? I've tried to implement this but am getting the error "myElementOne.setState is not a function".

Is there a another way I should be approaching this?

```
var App = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ElementOne id="abc12345"/>
                <ElementTwo/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var ElementOne = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return ({isShowing: true});
    },

    render() {
        if (this.state.isShowing) {
            return (
                <div id="abc12345">
                    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
                </div>
            );
        } else {
            return <div/>;
        }
    }
});

var ElementTwo = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return <a href="#" onClick={this.toggle.bind(null,this)}>Click here to Show/Hide!</a>;
    },

    toggle() {
        var myElementOne = document.getElementById("abc12345");
        myElementOne.setState({isShowing: false});
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('content'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in the following way: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/YGEmBE

The idea is to:

1. Maintain state in your parent component (`App`)
2. Pass this state to `ElementOne`
3. Pass ability to modify the state by a callback function passed to `ElementTwo`

Full code:

```
var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
      return ({
        isShowingInParent: true
      });
    },

    toggleInParent() {
      this.setState({
        isShowingInParent: !this.state.isShowingInParent
      });
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ElementOne id="abc12345" isShowing={this.state.isShowingInParent}/>
                <ElementTwo toggle={this.toggleInParent}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var ElementOne = React.createClass({
    render() {
        if (this.props.isShowing) {
            return (
                <div id="abc12345">
                    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
                </div>
            );
        } else {
            return <div/>;
        }
    }
});

var ElementTwo = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return <a href="#" onClick={this.props.toggle.bind(this)}>Click here to Show/Hide!</a>;
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('content'));
```

Comment: I've just updated my code and added additional explanation. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: partially yes, thank you :) but I'm still keen to understand whether or not there is a way to invoke another React element's setState without having to pass information via a parent node.  Do you know whether or not this can be done?  Or does a parent node always need to be used?

Comment: Sorry, I've missed your question. Without involving any third party libraries, you can pass information to grandchildren in pure React. This can be done using the context feature. Here you can find a nice summary of communication in react: http://andrewhfarmer.com/component-communication/, https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html, here are the React docs about context